# Tag has a lot of text I only need the titles , not description and extra details that are available in the nested tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to webscrape the url = "https://www.subko.coffee/pages/bombay-hyperlocal-store"
I want to isolate the tag but".text gives me a lot of extra text.
Ideal output :
Bombay Brie: Cherry Pop Tart
Pahadi Plum Twice Baked

```
website = requests.get("https://www.subko.coffee/pages/bombay-hyperlocal-store")
soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content,"html.parser")
coffees = soup.find_all("div",class_="pro-inners")

for coffee in coffees:
    name = coffee.find("div",class_="h4 product-card_title").find("div",class_="pro-detail").text
    print(name)
break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.subko.coffee/pages/bombay-hyperlocal-store')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
coffees = soup.select('div.pro-detail')
for coffee in coffees:
    print(coffee.contents[0].strip())
```

This returns:

```
Bombay Brie: Cherry Pop Tart
Pahadi Plum Twice Baked
Ginger Spiced Caramel Cookie
Subko Croissant
Subko Croissant [Egg Free]
Subko PAC
Subko PAC [Egg Free]
Twice Baked Badaam
[.....]
```